# Using EfCore lazy-loading proxies with blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I am having issues using proxies in EfCore with Blazor. If an object is passed to a sub-component that is accessing its proxied property sometime after the page has been loaded, context may have already been disposed, causing a crash

> An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Description' on entity type
>   'WeatherForecastProxy' after the associated DbContext was disposed.

Lazy Loading Proxies are needed to avoid Cartesian explosion in master/detail style user interfaces, where each entity in main list has its own sublist of owned entities, that in turn, have their own joins.

Minimal reproducible project based on official blazor template is at:  https://github.com/alextech/sample_use_proxy_blazor

[Utility Base Component class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope) is supposed to be a solution for sharing services between components to avoid threading issues, as was suggested at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/18076 and https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10448, but it still causes a crash

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. 
>   This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.

Am I using that utility base component classes feature correctly, or using efcore/blazor combination in an unintended way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205264/discussion-on-question-by-alex-tech-using-efcore-lazy-loading-proxies-with-blazo).

Answer (score -1):

Don't pass directly DAL models into your components, map them before into ViewModels, that's a best practice.
If you try to access to your DAL models from Webassembly Client app it's just impossible